# CSS grid: How to align baseline of spanned row to the last row of other columns

Tags: css, alignment, css-grid

I want to align the baseline of a to c.

```css
#grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: baseline;
}
#a{
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
}
#b{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  background: yellow;
}
#c{
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="a">aaaaa</div>
  <div id="b">bbbbb</div>
  <div id="c">ccccc</div>
</div>
```

I tried making the outer grid a single row and wrap b and c into a single div with inline-whatever, but a still always align to b instead of c.

```css
#grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: baseline;
}
#a{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  padding:8px;
  background:red;
}
#d{
  display:inline-block;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}
#b{
  background:yellow;
}
#c{
  background:blue
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="a">aaaaa</div>
  <div id="d">
    <div id="b">bbbbb</div>
    <div id="c">ccccc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make a align baseline to c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to declare `align-items: last baseline`

[Can I Use `align-items: last baseline`?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_align-items_flex_context_last_baseline) is showing 85% global support.

Specification jargon can be found at [Flex Container Baselines](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines)

```css
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: last baseline;
}

#a {
  grid-row: span 2;
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
}
#b {
  background: yellow;
}

#c {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="a">aaaaa</div>
  <div id="b">bbbbb</div>
  <div id="c">ccccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't aware that `last baseline` exists.

Comment: I didn't either until I saw it in the list of [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#values). I made the effort to cross-browser check because I was skeptical that it was supported. [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_align-self_flex_context_last_baseline) is showing 85% support. Support appears to be less than a year old except for Firefox since 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Since `last baseline` is still relatively new (I am using Electron 19 which does not support), I am looking for alternatives. Referring to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209427/align-flex-box-items-to-baseline-of-last-text-line-in-a-block) about flex, turns out I have to wrap the inline-block into yet another container.

```css
#grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: baseline;
}
#a{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  padding:8px;
  background:red;
}
#d{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}
#b{
  background:yellow;
}
#c{
  background:blue
}
.inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="a">aaaaa</div>
  <div id="d">
    <div class="inline-block">
      <div id="b">bbbbb</div>
      <div id="c">ccccc</div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you were to declare both values, `#grid { align-items: baseline; align-items: last baseline; }`, I believe browsers that don't support the `last baseline` value will ignore that declaration and use the first declaration of `baseline`. Give it a try so that you'll have the correct declaration moving forward.